# Python OrderedDicts equal to a tolerance

Tags: python, numpy

I have 100 OrderedDicts like,

```
foo =  OrderedDict({
    'a': -0.1011,
    'b': 3.2022,
    'c': 0.0
})
```

where some of them are likely to be equal. For a list of 100 dicts like `foo`, I would like to find the indices of the unique items, where a given item is unique if its values are not equal to the values of any other dict, to a tolerance of 0.01. Importantly we can assume the order of the keys for all OrderedDicts in the list are the same. So I could do `np.isclose(foo.values(), baz.values(), atol=0.01)`, but I'd have to loop through 10000 times to compare them all; actually less b/c I could on-the-fly ignore those that are found to be redundant. But is there a more efficient approach to doing this?

Another approach is something like: `uniques = {tuple(x.values()) for x in list_of_ord_dicts}`, but how could I incorporate a tolerance here?

Comment: Are you looking at all of the values for all of the dictionaries together, or all of the values *per key* for all of the dictionaries?

Comment: @James per key. So if `baz = {'a': -0.1011, 'b': 0.0, 'c': 3.2022}`, then `foo != baz`.

Comment: `I would like to find the indices of the unique items` - So, with that foo and `baz = {'a': -0.1011, 'b': 0.0, 'c': 3.2022}`, what's the expected output as the index? Or would that be the key names?

Comment: @Divakar the list is `[foo, baz, ...]`, so dicts are the items, and I would like the indices of the unique dicts in the list.

Comment: So, indices of the dicts that have all the keys unique w.r.t the values in all other dicts for all of those keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `stuff` is the list of dicts and I want my tolerance to be `d` decimals:

```
import numpy as np
_, ind = np.unique(np.array([np.round(s.values(), d) for s in stuff]), axis=0, return_index=True)
```

where `ind` are the indices of `stuff` referencing the unique dicts.

Comment: Note this requires [numpy v1.13 for unique](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) to have the axis param.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably overkill but it should run fast and is simple to read. It runs the K-Means algorithm to find clusters within .01. You'll need sklearn.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from random import random
from copy import copy
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import cluster

hundred_dicts = [OrderedDict(a=random(), b=random(), c=random()) for _ in range(90)]
hundred_dicts.extend(copy(hundred_dicts[:10]))

df = pd.DataFrame(hundred_dicts)
kmeans = cluster.KMeans(
        n_clusters=len(hundred_dicts),
        random_state=0,
        tol=0.01).fit(df)
labels = kmeans.labels_
df['cluster'] = kmeans.labels_
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='cluster')
```